# Calling swe_calc_ut() from swedll32.dll

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to draw natal chart using swedll32.dll in c#. when I call function swe_calc_ut() using dllimport very first it gives me correct result . but If i call any other function of swedll32.dll before this and after that make a call to swe_calc_ut() then it returns NaN values in result double[].
here is the code..

**Main.cs**

```
Class Main
{

UniversalTOBUTJD = Sweph.swe_julday(birthTimeUTC.Year, birthTimeUTC.Month,    
birthTimeUTC.Day, birthTimeUTC.TimeOfDay.TotalHours);
double[] tret = new Double[6] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
Sweph.swe_calc_ut(UniversalTOBUTJD , 0, 0, tret);**/// this returns NaN in tret arrey**


}
```

and if I try like below: here I used hard coded value for universal time, which I got by calling Sweph.swe_julday() function

```
{

 Sweph.swe_calc_ut(2443436.659722222, 0, 0, tret); **/// this returns correct values in tret array**
 UniversalTOBUTJD = Sweph.swe_julday(birthTimeUTC.Year, birthTimeUTC.Month,    
 birthTimeUTC.Day, birthTimeUTC.TimeOfDay.TotalHours);
 double[] tret = new Double[6] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

}
```

**Sweph.cs**
Class Sweph
{

```
   [DllImport("swedll32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "swe_julday")]
    public extern static double xyz_swe_julday(int year, int month, int day, double hour, int gregflag);   //no

    /// <summary>
    /// swe_julday - It computes year, month, day and hour from a Julian day number
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="year">Year</param>
    /// <param name="month">Month</param>
    /// <param name="day">Day</param>
    /// <param name="hour">Hour</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the Julian day</returns>
    public static double swe_julday(int year, int month, int day, double hour)
    {
        return xyz_swe_julday(year, month, day, hour, 1);
    }

    [DllImport("swedll32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "swe_calc_ut")]
    private extern static int xyz_swe_calc_ut(double tjd_ut, int ipl, int iflag, 
    double[] xx, StringBuilder serr);

    /// <summary>
    /// swe_calc_ut - Compute a planet or other bodies
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tjd_ut">Julian day, Universal Time</param>
    /// <param name="ipl">planet number</param>
    /// <param name="addFlags">a 32bit integercontaining bit flags that indicate what kind of computation wanted</param>
    /// <param name="xx">array of 6 doubles for Longitude,latitude,distance,speed in long, speed in lat and speed in dist</param>
    //public static void getPlanet(double tjd_ut, int ipl, int addFlags, double[] xx)
  public static void swe_calc_ut(double tjd_ut, int ipl, int addFlags, double[] xx)
    {

        StringBuilder serr = new StringBuilder(256);

        int ret = xyz_swe_calc_ut(tjd_ut, ipl, iflag | addFlags, xx, serr);

    }
```

}

please help I really stuck here.

Comment: What is the definition of the functions? Can you post the relevant parts from the header file? Also, are the functions StdCall or CDecl?

Comment: Hi shashank, did you resolve this issue somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

Before calling swe_calc_ut you should set path to a folder with ephe data like this:

```
[DllImport("swedll32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "swe_set_ephe_path")]
private static extern void swe_set_ephe_path(String swe_path);

swe_set_ephe_path(@"c:\path\to\ephe\");
```